# Passing parameters using AZ CLI for ARM template deployment

Tags: azure-devops, azure-powershell

I am trying to use `az group deployment create` to perform an ARM template deployment and I want to pass in parameters where the values are defined in variables. I can do a single parameter with no issues using the syntax below:

`--parameters parameter1=$var1`

But when I try to add additional parameters using the syntax below, it fails:

`--parameters parameter1=$var1, parameter2=$var2`

The syntax below fails as well since it will not use the values of the variables:

```
    --parameters '{
        "parameter1": { "value": "$var1" },
        "parameter2": { "value": "$var2" }
    }'
```

Does anyone know if what I am trying to do is possible and what the correct syntax would be?

Comment: Have you tried as in your second codeblock but without the comma?  It looks like the syntax is --parameters param1=val1 param2=val2
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/deploy-cli

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was fighting a combination of a corrupt shell and slightly incorrect syntax. The correct syntax for what I was trying to do is listed below:

```
--parameters parameter1=$var1 parameter2=$var2
```

Or, for a cleaning view when several parameters are involved:

```
--parameters parameter1=$var1 `
    parameter2=$var2 `
    parameter3=$var3
```

Comment: Great work! You can [accept it as answer](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/) so that more members with similar issue can benefit from that. Just a reminder :)